# I am getting 'org/neo4j/kernel/impl/core/RelationshipTypeHolder ' error while Running spring data neo4j configuration

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest, spring-data-graph

I have changed dependency of neo4j-kernel version but still getting this issue. Please suggest to me how to get rid out of this issue. Below are my pom, spring configuration and error console.

**Dependency in pom :**

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.M01</version>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M06</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Spring configuration:**

```
    <bean id="restGraphDatabase"
        class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
        <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data/" />
    </bean> 


    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="restGraphDatabase" />
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="com.neo.repodb" />
```

**Console Error:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/kernel/impl/core/RelationshipTypeHolder
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/kernel/impl/core/RelationshipTypeHolder
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:384)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:322)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:840)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipTypeHolder
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        ... 45 more

    Nov 17, 2013 1:44:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    SEVERE: Servlet /opinion threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipTypeHolder
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        at java.la
```

Comment: Remove the neo4j-kernel dependency and the neo4j exclusion from the spring-data-neo4j dependency, SDN just carries the correct neo4j version on.

Comment: Thanks remigio..but still getting the same error :(

Comment: You could use the *mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose* command to analyze inclusion of jars and try to detect where is the issue, the class you need is included in the *neo4j-kernel* jar.

Comment: Remove the neo4j-cypher artifact too, it pulls in all of neo4j 2.0 which is not compatible with SDN 2.3.